# ModernHttpClient returns Forbidden on Azure Blob upload in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-blob-storage, dotnet-httpclient

I'm attempting to update an existing, working Xamarin app to use ModernHttpClient. The app uses Azure REST calls to create containers and upload blobs to Azure Storage.

When I add `new  NativeMessageHandler()` to each `new HttpClient()` statement to enable ModernHttpClient, the Azure Container continues to get created without any problem, but the call to upload the Blob returns Forbidden.

Here's the code to upload blobs (derived from other's work):

```
private async Task<bool> PutBlob(String containerName, String blobName, string photoPath)       
 {
            byte[] blobContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(photoPath);            

            const String blobType = "BlockBlob";
            String requestMethod = "PUT";
            Int32 blobLength = blobContent.Length;

            String urlPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", containerName, blobName);
            String msVersion = "2009-09-19";
            String dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            String canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format("x-ms-blob-type:{0}\nx-ms-date:{1}\nx-ms-version:{2}", blobType, dateInRfc1123Format, msVersion);
            String canonicalizedResource = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", AzureStorageConstants.Account, urlPath);
            String stringToSign = String.Format("{0}\n\n\n{1}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{2}\n{3}", requestMethod, blobLength, canonicalizedHeaders, canonicalizedResource);
            String authorizationHeader = SignThis(stringToSign);

            string uri = AzureStorageConstants.BlobEndPoint + urlPath;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-blob-type", blobType);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", dateInRfc1123Format);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", msVersion);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);

            bool isSuccess = false;
            var UploadBlobTimer = Insights.TrackTime("UploadBlobTime");
            UploadBlobTimer.Start();
                using (HttpContent requestContent = new ByteArrayContent(blobContent))
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(uri, requestContent);
                    isSuccess = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

                }
            UploadBlobTimer.Stop();           

            return isSuccess;            
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Below are the Response Headers from a successful .Net and unsuccessful Modern PutBlob call:

**.Net**

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked  
ETag: 0x8D280EE1D2ACEFF  
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0  
x-ms-request-id: 0a35e186-0001-0056-4dd6-b22ebd000000  
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19  
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 01:49:18 GMT
```

**Modern**

```
Date: Tue, 30 Jun 2015 01:51:22 GMT  
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1435629095708  
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1  
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1435629083933  
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0  
x-ms-request-id: c18abaec-0001-0033-09d7-b29fe0000000
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does the error response contains string-to-sign server used to authenticate your request?

Comment: Thanks @Serdar, I looked at the ReasonPhrase and it is related to the header Auth header: **"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."** Is there something I need to do to make this work with ModernHttpClient, given it works fine with System.Net.Http?

Comment: My guess is that `ModernHttpClient` is modifying the request in some way that changes the string-to-sign. Server should send back the string-to-sign used on the server side back to the client in the error response. Is it possible to look at the request/response details using a tool like Fiddler?

Comment: It's strange that Create Container is working but Upload Blob is not - given they're both signed the same way. I'm wondering if the blob length isn't being reported correctly. I'm hoping someone has seen this problem before! In the meantime, I have to setup fiddler to inspect the details...

Comment: Also are you purposefully using an old version of the Azure API: `String msVersion = "2009-09-19";`?

Comment: No, just following example code.  Changed to `msVersion = "2014-02-14"` and same outcome: Container gets created but blob returns Forbidden.